# Let a,b,c be non-negative integers. Prove that if $a+2b+3c\geq 5$, then $a\geq 3$, $b\geq 2$ or $c\geq 1$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-explanation

This is a problem from Discrete Mathematics by Chartrand and Zhang and it is supposed to be proven by contrapositive. In the answers at the back of the book they find the negation of $Q$ to be $\neg Q=a\leq 2, b\leq 1$ and $c\leq 0$, I can't seem to figure out how they get this.

To me it appears as though $Q=(a\geq 3\cap b\geq 2)\cup (c\geq 1)$ then taking the negation of this gives $$\neg Q=\neg((a\geq 3\cap b\geq 2)\cup(c\geq 1))\\ =\neg(a\geq 3\cap b\geq 2)\cap\neg(c\geq 1)\\ =(\neg(a\geq 3)\cup\neg(b\geq 2))\cap(c\leq 0)\\=((a\leq 2)\cup (b\leq 1))\cap(c\leq 0)\\ = ((a\leq 2)\cap(c\leq 0))\cup((b\leq 1)\cap(c\leq 0))$$

so I find $a\leq 2$, $c\leq 0$ or $b\leq 1$, $c\leq 0$. I can see how they got their result but it doesn't really make sense since they're just taking the negation of both the statements individually.

Comment: I think what they authors meant was $a\geq 3$ , $b\geq 2$ or $c\geq 1$ all separately. Otherwise, the negation is not $a\leq 2, b\leq 1$ and $c=0.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that by "$a\geq 3, b\geq 2$ or $c\geq 1$" they meant "$a\geq 3$ or $b\geq 2$ or $c\geq 1$", whereas you've interpreted it as "$(a\geq 3,b\geq 2)$ or $c\geq 1$". Their intended meaning is true, but your interpretation isn't which is why your contrapositive isn't working.

So you should have $Q=(a\geq 3)\cup(b\geq 2)\cup(c\geq 1)$.

Answer (score 2):

That's long-winded. If it isn't the case that $a\ge 3$, $b\ge 2$ or $c\ge1$ holds, then all of three conditions fails, that is all of $a<3$, $b<2$ and $c<1$ hold. But $a$, $b$, $c$ are integers, so $a\le2$, $b\le 1$ and $c\le0$. (Then $a+2b+3c\le4$.)

Comment: This makes sense and all but shouldn't it also follow from applying DeMorgan's Theorem?

Comment: @Craig exactly! it's the three-proposition form of one of the De Morgan laws.